# Python beginner - extracting an int from a list item

Tags: python, list, int

For my first programming 'project' i am making a simple program that asks user to input the AUD amount and it will convert to Chinese RMB. I found some code that scrapes the current conversion rate from a website but it comes in the form of `CNY/AUD = 5.75218`. I just want to extract the `5.75218` number to multiply by the user input. I have done alot of searches and can not find a solution to this. Any advice would be appreciated!!

```
from lxml import html
import requests
import re



page = requests.get('http://themoneyconverter.com/AUD/CNY.aspx')
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)


rate =  (tree.xpath('//textarea[@id="ratebox"]/text()'))


print 'The Exchange Rate is:  ', rate
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume that `rate` is `CNY/AUD = 5.75218`. When dealing with money I would suggest using `Decimal` in order to exactly represents decimal numbers:

```
from decimal import Decimal

...

rate = Decimal(rate.split()[2])
```

Infact try thinking about the following. Imagine that you always have an income given by

```
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1
```

Now imagine that you have a payment that is always of 0.3. Math says that your earnings equals to 0:

```
0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3 = 0
```

Imagine that you have these scenario `10**20` times:

```
(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3) * 10**20 = 0
```

Your earnings are still equal to 0. Try now doing it in python shell and suppose we are talking about dollars:

```
(0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 - 0.3) * 10**20 = ?
```

You have just earned around 5551 USD.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `split` method.

For `rate = "CNY/AUD = 5.75218"` you may try the following code

```
rate = rate.split()
```

to make `rate` become `['CNY/AUD', '=', '5.75218']`. Then you pick the 3rd element in `rate` and convert it to float:

```
rate = float(rate[2])
```

Refer to http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_split.htm for details about `split`.